# Fixed No of Rows per each page while printing in Pdf format using FPDF in Codeifniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, fpdf

I Have a Table in that 31 records are there.when I click on the print button data showing on the PDF format fine.But is taking by default 16 rows per page.I want to display 10 rows per each.How would i do that.I am new to codeigniter and FPDF Please somebody help me thanks in Advance.

### This is my function in view for printing data in pdf format

```
function viewdata($result){
if(isset($result)){
foreach($result as $values){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',10.5);
  $this->Cell(60,10,$values['vndr_name'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(90,10,$values['vndr_address'].','.$values['state'].'-'.$values['vndr_pincode'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(50,10,$values['vndr_telephone'].','.$values['vndr_mobile'],1,0,'L');
  $this->Cell(70,10,$values['vndr_mailid'],1,0,'L');
  $this->ln();
}
}
}

$this->pdf = new Printview();
$this->pdf->SetMargins(15, 10, 20);
$this->pdf->AliasNbPages();
$this->pdf->AddPage('L','A4',0);
$this->pdf->viewdata($result);
$this->pdf->Output();
```

### this is my controller code

```
public function printpage(){
   $this->load->library('fpdf/fpdf');
   $data['result']=$this->Vendor_Model->displaydata();
   if(!empty(array_filter($data))){
   $this->load->view('printview',$data);
  }
  else{
    redirect('Vendorcontroller/showeditview');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the page on every 10 rows by appending `AddPage()` methods :

```
function viewdata($result){
    if(isset($result)){
        $total_row = count($result); // get the total row
        $i = 0;
        foreach($result as $values){
            $this->SetFont('Arial','',10.5);
            $this->Cell(60,10,$values['vndr_name'],1,0,'L');
            $this->Cell(90,10,$values['vndr_address'].','.$values['state'].'-'.$values['vndr_pincode'],1,0,'L');
            $this->Cell(50,10,$values['vndr_telephone'].','.$values['vndr_mobile'],1,0,'L');
            $this->Cell(70,10,$values['vndr_mailid'],1,0,'L');
            $this->ln();
            if (++$i % 10 == 0 && $i != $total_row) { // add a page break on every 10 row & prevent adding an extra page if it is the last row
                $this->AddPage('L','A4',0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My output didn't change.I am getting data as earlier by default no of rows only.

Comment: I have checked your updated answer also .if i use $I variable outside foreach it is giving error.If i used inside foreach it is giving default output only.

Comment: Could you try to append `$this->pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);` after `$this->pdf->AliasNbPages();`?

Comment: Same results only nothing change.